# python how do I determine screen size

Tags: python

I need to resize an image.  The original is 1024x768.  My laptop screen is set to 1366x768.  When I go to view the image the bottom is always cut off.  I'm guessing it's because the image is 1024x768 but the image size doesn't take into account the box/window the image sits in, so the bottom of the image gets cuts off as a result.

What is the size, pixelwise, of the box/window and how do I determine the size of my screen, codewise, so I can reset the size of the image so the entire image will fit on the screen and none of it will get cut off.  Or is there a way of having the image autoscale so it will fit the screen height resolution?  I'm using PIL.

I know I can in the end just

```
new_image = old_image.resize(x, 768-box_height)
```

I just need to know the box height.

Answer (score 2):

The most environment-agnostic way is likely to just ask `tkinter`:

```
import tkinter #python 3 syntax

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

width, height = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
```

Comment: That gives the actual screen resolution which does help.  How do I find out what the height of the box that goes around the gui, namely the top of the gui.  My image is 768, the same as the screen size but the bottom always gets chopped off.  I figure I'm going to have to shrink the dimensions so the box will be taken into consideration toward the y=768.

Comment: @confused PIL doesn't really know.  It gives it up to whatever your OS decides to open the file with - `xv` on *nix, generally, and probably paint (?) on windows.  There's no easy way to find out what the window frame bounds are going to be.